Get Day Index of specific Week
i try to get the index of a specific week from 0 to 6.
This is working correctly for contries where the week starts from Monday to Sunday.
fun getDayOfWeek(date: LocalDate): Int {
    val dayOfWeek = date.dayOfWeek.value - 1
    return dayOfWeek
}

The Probelem is now, if there is a country that has the week starting with Sunday to Saturday like the US. How to get the day of week index given by the localization of the Smartphone?
So that it returns 0 to 6 (Monday to Sunday) for the countries where the week starts with Monday and also 0 to 6 (Sunday to Saturday) for countries where the week start with Sunday?
